# bash: [: too many arguments after rvm get stable

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting, rvm

As the title says, after running the `rvm get stable` code in bash, I started getting an error, `-bash: [: too many arguments`.  This error pops up when I do any command, but executes the command properly.  `ls` and `cd` for instance will execute as expected, but then print out the error.

I'm running macOS Sierra.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is the code?  What is your `PS1` set to?

Comment: When I do `echo $PS1` I get `\n \[\e[36;1m\]2017-06-05 21:14:11 \[\e[0;31m\]☆ \[\e[0;33m\] \[\e[0;35m\]\h \[\e[39m\]in \[\e[0;32m\]\w\n\[\e[36;1m\]○\[\e[0;32m\] \[\e[0;32m\]→\[\e[39m\]`

Comment: Can we see your `.bashrc`?

Comment: Sure, it's just 1 line, `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting`

Comment: Adding to that last comment, that was the code in .bashrc in ~, I went to the bashrc file in /etc/ and it had this: 

`# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize

[ -r "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM" ] && . "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this issue, I was able to stop the error message from showing up by removing the following line of code from ~/.profile and ~/.bash_profile:

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*`

This was added by updating rvm, which is still working after these lines being removed.

UPDATE: This stopped the error, but popped my ruby version backwards from 2.2 back to 2.0

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after running `rvm get stable`.

Since `rvm` needs to run in the shell session as a function, removing the line `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` from your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` is not an option.

On my environment the cause was due to a conflict between an old installation of [bash-it](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it) and rvm. If you're using `bash-it` and encountering this issue, this may help.

I took the following steps:

1. Backed up my `.bash_profile` (if you have `.bashrc` you may want to back it up as well).
2. Ran `bash-it`'s uninstall script (see instructions in the link above) and removed `~/.bash-it` folder.
3. Reinstalled `bash-it`.
4. Added to `.bash_profile` what was missing based on my `.bash_profile` backup created on step 1.
5. Reenabled the `bash-it` aliases, completions, and plugins that I needed.

As soon as I opened a new shell, I stopped receiving the error and `rvm` started working properly.